# Is it possible to get details of the email for which user had replied?

Tags: java, email, amazon-ses

I am using amazon SES to send notification emails in my project. When a user replies back to this email I want to trigger some actions (like a ticket creation or update). Is it possible to know the contents or headers of the email for which user is replying ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the replying user's email system supports it (most do), you should receive an `In-Reply-To:` Header containing the message-id of the email you sent. If you kept that message (along with the message id) you can use this to retrieve original email.

Sometimes the `Refereces:` Header might be useful as well

Comment: My actual requirement is in my notification email i will be setting a header with the customer id,  and when user replies to this email I would like to read this from the reply email

Comment: Sorry - apart from the In-Reply-To and References no headers of the original email will be returned. You might get lucky if you put customer-id in Subject (as most of the time replies will Re: the original subject